# zero-or-one to zero-or-one

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, foreign-key

How do I model zero-or-one to zero-or-one relationship in Sql Server the most natural way?

There is a 'Hazard' table that lists hazards on a site. There is a 'Task' table for work that needs to be done on a site. Some Tasks are to fix a hazard, no task can deal with multiple hazards. Some Hazards have a task to fix them. No hazard can have two tasks associated with them.

The below is the best I could think of:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Hazard](
  [HazardId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [TaskId] [int] NULL,
  [Details] [varchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Hazard] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
  [HazardId] ASC
))

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Hazard]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Hazard_Task] FOREIGN KEY([TaskId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Task] ([TaskId])
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Task](
  [TaskId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [HazardId] [int] NULL,
  [Details] [varchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Task] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
  [TaskId] ASC
))

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Task_Hazard] FOREIGN KEY([HazardId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Hazard] ([HazardId])
GO
```

Would you do that differently? The reason I'm not happy with this set up is that there need to be application logic to make sure that tasks and hazards point to each other and not to other task and hazards and that no task/hazard points to the same hazard/task another task/hazard points to.

Is there a better way?

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason you could not create a unique index on TaskID on the Hazard table and a unique index of HazardID on the Task table?   That would make it so that you could only have one of them in the table, which is I think what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @mskinner but they are not unique, many of them can be `null`.

Comment: ah, gotcha.   In that case Mr. Ben-Gan has a great write up on how to create that constraint to allow multiple nulls here  http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2008/unique-constraint-multiple-nulls .  I think that will work for you.  Let me know if not.

Comment: As a side note to that, there are a number of issues using filtered indexes, so it would probably be worth reading up on them if you are not familiar.   Here is a good blog on that.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2009/06/29/interesting-issue-with-filtered-indexes.aspx  ,   But for this specific scenario, it might work well for you, assuming the other issues do not cause you too much grief.

Comment: FWIW a unique filtered index can apply uniqueness only to the non-null rows, e.g. `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX x ON dbo.Hazards(TaskID) WHERE TaskID IS NOT NULL;`

Comment: Could you help me to make sure I understand the problem? If a Task references a Hazard, no other Task can reference the same Hazard. (N.B. This is where a filtered unique index would help.) If the referenced Hazard references a Task, it can only be the same Task that references the Hazard. (N.B. This is the harder part.) And the same should apply if we swap "Task" and "Hazard". Is that correct?

Comment: @AndriyM It looks like the filtered unique indices will solve it. In the absence of the indices task1 can reference hazard1. (task.hazardid = hazard.hazardid) and task 2 also can reference hazard1. This needs to be avoided. moreover it is possible that task1 references hazard1 but hazard1 references task2 (hazard.taskid = task.taskid). That's also to be avoided. Does this make it more understandable?

Comment: Yes, thanks, that confirms my understanding of it. Please note that the filtered unique indices won't help you with this part: `it is possible that task1 references hazard1 but hazard1 references task2 (hazard.taskid = task.taskid). That's also to be avoided` (which is what I regarded in my rendering as "the harder part").

Comment: @AndriyM yep, realize this. It appears that if I simply remove TaskId column from Hazard table completely that would work though. The schema will become asymmetric, regarding the two tables, but as far as I can see will satisfy the requirement. (with the filtered index in-place.)

Comment: That was what I contemplated suggesting but then I thought you specifically wanted the mutual referencing because you wanted to prevent easy (accidental) deletion of a Task or a Hazard where the two are connected to each other. (With either of the asymmetrical designs, you could break the connection by removing just one of the two sides.)

Comment: @AndriyM, nope that was not my line of thoughts. I was simply wondering about the most natural way of doing this, and that's what came to mind.

Comment: I would go with asymmetry then. The only problem would then be to decide which table should reference which, but I guess only you can tell. If you choose this way eventually, please consider posting that as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could go with [your own idea](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/111625/zero-or-one-to-zero-or-one?noredirect=1#comment202444_111625) of an asymmetric schema by removing one of the foreign keys from the current set-up, or, to keep things symmetric, you could remove both foreign keys and introduce a [junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) with a unique constraint on each reference.

So, it would be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Hazard
(
  HazardId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Hazard PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
  Details varchar(max) NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Task
(
  TaskId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Task PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
  Details varchar(max) NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.HazardTask
(
  HazardId int NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT FK_HazardTask_Hazard FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Hazard (HazardId)
    CONSTRAINT UQ_HazardTask_Hazard UNIQUE,
  TaskId int NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT FK_HazardTask_Task FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Task (TaskId)
    CONSTRAINT UQ_HazardTask_Task UNIQUE
);
```

You could additionally declare `(HazardId, TaskId)` to be the primary key if you need to reference these combinations from another table. For the purpose of keeping the pairs unique, however, the primary key is unnecessary, it is enough that each ID is unique.

Comment: +1 I thinks this is the most natural way to implement such a relation. but usualy one select a tuple as primary only if it is minimal The tuple `(HazardId, TaskId)` has the tuples `(HazardId)`and `(TaskId)` that both identify a row of this table uniquely. One of them should be selected as primary key.

Answer (score 2):

To sum up:

- Hazards have one or zero Tasks
- Tasks have one or zero Hazards

If the Task and Hazard tables are used for something else (i.e. tasks and/or hazards have other data associated, and the model you showed to us is simplified to show only the relevant fields) I'd say that your solution is correct.

Otherwise, if Tasks and Hazards only exist to be coupled to each other, you don't need two tables; you can create a single table for their relationship, with the following fields:

```
ID            int, PK
TaskID        int, (filtered) unique index  
TaskDetails   varchar
HazardID      int, (filtered) unique index
HazardDetails varchar
```

Comment: I took the liberty of clarifying that it should be a filtered index in each case, (though it could be guessed from the description of the problem, it may not look entirely obvious). Please feel free to edit further if you feel that unnecessary or want to convey the idea in a different way.

Comment: I must say I'm still not really happy with this idea. The issue is I'd have to generate TaskID and HazardID manually. If this was 2012, it would be possible to use sequences for that, but even then it wouldn't seem right to me. I guess it's because the two things, tasks and hazards, are completely different entities and so it's hard to reconcile with the idea of storing them in a single table.

Comment: If this design is chosen, why do we need the `TaskID` and `HazardID`? You could have 2 BIT columns, `IsTask`, `IsHazard` and a constraint that not both of them are false. Then the `Hazard` table is simply a view: `CRAETE VIEW Hazard SELECT HazardID = ID, HazardDetails, ... FROM ThisTable WHERE IsHazard = 1;` and Task respectively.

Comment: @ypercube You'd be storing a shapeless thing in a table and then use a binary field to tell whether it's a Task or a Hazard. It's ugly database modeling.

Comment: @AndriyM I understand, and I agree that, *in most cases*, we should not store two kinds of different entities in the same table. However, read my caveat: if Tasks and Hazards are in a 1-to-1 relationship and exist *only for this*, then it's acceptable to use a single table.

Comment: @dr01 I never claimed it was nice, I like AndriyM's design far better! You suggested this ;) I was only suggesting replacing 2 INT columns with 2 BIT ones. I don't see any difference in ugliness.

Comment: By the way, what is this "shapeless" thing? I don't understand.

Comment: Yes, except they are not in a 1-to-1 relationship, as indeed you have summarised that yourself at the beginning of your answer. I mean, 1 to 1 is not the same as 0-or-1 to 0-or-1, that is why I think a single table may not be a good solution. I'm not trying to be pedantic, by the way. If a task can be without a hazard as well as a hazard without a task, you can't say they exist only for this 1-to-1 relationship.

Comment: @AndriyM Agreed. I meant 0-or-1 to 0-or-1 indeed. Thanks for pointing this out. Still, I see the single table as a viable solution -- of course, some `TaskID` or `HazardID` will be null.

Comment: You are right in that I gave a simplified version. Of course both Task and Hazard *objects* are more complex than described and have a slew of their own unique properties. Thus, having them in one table unfortunately won't work for me, but thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that seems not to have been mentioned yet is to have Hazards and Tasks use the same ID space. If a Hazard has a Task, it will have the same ID. If a Task is for a Hazard it will have the same ID.

You would use a sequence rather than identity columns to populate these IDs.

Queries on this type of data model would use (full) outer joins to retrieve their results.

This approach is very similar to @AndriyM's answer except his answer allows for the IDs being different, and a table to store this relationship.

I'm not sure you want to use this approach for a two-table scenario, but it works well when the number of tables involved increases.

Comment: Thank you for contributing, I've considered that approach too. I decided against it in the end because sequence is awkward to implement in sql2008 and more trouble than I'd willing to put up with.